# 'ls -alF' doesn't list files in directories behind symbolic links?

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I've grown accustomed to see file-lists like this: `ll /media/sf_G_DRIVE`  (ls -alF)
[image: screenshot]
but I've recently starting to use symbolic directories, but using `ll /g` don't show the files, it only displays that /g is a symbolic link and where it goes
[image: screenshot]

I've tried different ls combination, but haven't found any that displays the /g correctly.. (with this "fine" layout)
unless you first change the directory to /g and then do ll...

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ls` is doing this because you’re asking it to: the `-F` and `-l` options [instruct `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) to *not* follow symbolic links given as arguments unless the `-H` or `-L` options are specified.

Adding `/` at the end of the link name forces the argument to be considered as a directory:

```
ll /g/
```

You can also specify `-H` instead:

```
ls -alFH /g
ll -H /g
```